# Como faço para atribuir uma view a um input do tipo submit?

Tags: css, html5, laravel

Eu quero atribuir uma blade a um input em meu código.
Por exemplo: A view se chama 'painel.blade' e eu queria que um input na view 'adm.blade' retornasse ela.

Controller

class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    public function showClient($id){
        $client = \App\Clients::find($id);
        return view('showclient')->with('client', $client);
    }

```
public function adm()
{
    $clients = \App\Clients::all();
    return View('/inicioadm')->with('clients', $clients);
}

public function des()
{
    $clients = \App\Clients::all()->where('Tipo', 'Desenvolvedor');
    return View('/iniciodes')->with('clients', $clients);
}

public function painel()
{
    $user = \App\User::all();
    return view('painel', ['users' => $user]);
}

public function ativar($id)
{
    $estado = \App\User::find($id);
    if ($estado->Estado == 0){
        $estado->Estado = 1;
        $estado->save();
    }
    return redirect('/painel');               
}

public function desativar($id)
{
    $estado = \App\User::find($id);
    if ($estado->Estado == 1){
        $estado->Estado = 0;
        $estado->save();
    }
    return redirect ('/painel');
}
```

inicioadm.blade

```
<form method="POST" action="inicioadm">

     <h1> BEM VINDO ADMINISTRADOR! </h1> 

</form>

@foreach ($clients as $client)
    <p><a href="/cliente/{{$client->ID}}">{{$client->Nome}}</a></p>
@endforeach

<input type="submit" value="Clientes" id="clientes" name="Clientes">


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi corretamente sua dúvida, mas se for para mandar por esse btn sua aplicação para outra págida do blade no caso panel tendo a rota criada você poderia usar (Não sei ser é a melhor forma):

```
<input type="submit" value="Clientes" id="clientes" name="Clientes" onclick="location.href='{{ route('informe sua rota aqui') }}'" >
```

OU ainda (Talvez mais recomendado nesse caso)

```
<a id="btn" href="{{ route('informe sua rota aqui') }}"></a>
```